# Picker Value into tableView swift

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, picker

The first text field is a Int Value where you insert your current sold. A second one textfield where I get some Int value and add to a tableView with a button. The value you add into the second textfield soustract to the main value ( in that case 2500 ). That's working great.

My problem is to attribuate the PickerValue to the TableRow Value. it's working but not like I want.

I want to save the pickerValue when i click onto the button. But when i enter a new value it's changing all row of the pickerValue. In that case, you can see two row with "telephone". Normaly it's would be "telephone" and something else ( "maison" or "house").

Do you see a reason why it's doing like this ? I wish you can understand what i mean.

[problem with picker value save into table view (gif)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbXUm.gif)

```
    @IBAction func addBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    
    view.endEditing(true)

    salaire = Int(salaireLabel.text!) ?? 0
    valeur =  Int(ressourceTextField.text!) ?? 0
    
    if  String(valeur) != "" {
        
        addBtnActivated = true
        
        restValueLabel.textColor = UIColor.blue
        
        arrayRessource.append(valeur)
        

        // modifie automatiquement le salaire
        restValueLabel.text = String(soustraction)
    
        tableRessourceOT.reloadData()
        
        // reset le champs
        ressourceTextField.text = ""
        picker.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
    
    }

}
```

Here is some code I'm using. I'm thinking the problem came from the tableview Func

```
var arrayPickerValue: [String] = ["", "maison", "telephone"] 

// ------------------------------ START PICKER ------------------------------------

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    print("-----arraypicker.count------")
    print(arrayPickerValue.count)
    return arrayPickerValue.count
}

// hauteur du picker pour que les images ne se supperpose pas / Picker height
  func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, rowHeightForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
 return 25
 }

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    print("----arraypicker[row]----")
    print(arrayPickerValue[row])
    return arrayPickerValue[row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    stored = arrayPickerValue[row]
    print("-----stored dans func didselectrow------")
    print(stored as Any)
}
```

//-------------------------- END PICKER -----------------------------------

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    let row = indexPath.row
    let value =  arrayRessource[row]

    
    cell.textLabel?.text = "- " + String(value) + " €"
        
  //  cell.detailTextLabel?.text =
    
    updateRestLabel()
    
    setRestLabel()
  
    return cell
}
```

Here is my outlet :

@IBOutlet weak var tableRessourceOT: UITableView!

Then my arrayRessource :

```
    var arrayRessource: [Int] = [] {
    didSet {
        if oldValue != arrayRessource {
            userDefault.setValue(arrayRessource, forKey: arrayKey)
        }
    }
}
```

and call with the function :

```
    func getArray() {
    if let newArray = userDefault.array(forKey: arrayKey) as? [Int] {
        arrayRessource = newArray
    }
}
```

Comment: in my viewdidLoad have the deleage like that : picker.delegate = self
picker.dataSource = self

Comment: Your picker view's `didSelectRow` method saves the user's selected row in a variable 'stored`. You never reference that variable anywhere else in your code. You never show the button code that is supposed to add a picker value to your table view, you never show how you changed your `arrayRessource` which feeds your table view, and you don't explain how the values in your picker view (2500) relate to the entries in your table view (-2 Euro, etc). You need to provide a lot more, and clearer, information about how your app is supposed to work. (Edit your question, don't add comments.)

Comment: How can i populate my Int TableView with PickerView String ? i think it's here my problem what do you think about it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem come from my array was an Int array and my pickerValue was String array.

Array can't be String array's and Int array's.

```
    var arrayRessource: [String] = [] {
    didSet {
        if oldValue != arrayRessource {
            userDefault.setValue(arrayRessource, forKey: arrayKey)
        }
    }
}
```

Thanx for your advice by the way i'm progressing and doing my best

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear.
However I will make an attempt to offer some help from what I can extract from your code.

I assume `restValueLabel` is not something within your cells? It is probably the green label "2500" in your screenshot?
If that is the case, don't set it in `cellForRow(at:)`. This method is called every time a cell becomes visible and should **only** be used to configure that very cell based on your data source (`arrayRessource`).

Instead create a method `updateRestValueLabel()` that iterates your data source, does the calculation and sets the appropriate value to your `restValueLabel`. Call that method every time your data source changes, so along with `tableRessourceOT.reloadData()`.

There are also some stylistic issues with your code (e.g. avoid force unwrapping `!` unless you have good reason to use it) but this is out of scope here.

Comment: The restValueLabel il the soustract of the sold label and the value into the table.